# Deeplink problem when application working in the background (Braze provider), React Native, iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, deep-linking, braze

I'm facing an issue with deeplinks when sending from braze account. Deeplinks should open me some let's say popup in the app. When the app is closed and I send a push notification from Braze, I will receive it on my ios mobile device, when I click it, it will redirect me to the onboarding page (if deeplink is set to be "onboarding"), but if my app is working in background and I receive push notification with deeplink, when I click that push notification it will just open the app and it will not navigate me to the wanted screen.

I have appDelegate.mm file and this is defined inside it

```
// Deep Linking
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  NSLog(@"Calling RCTLinkingManager with url %@", url);
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

// Universal links
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
  continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
  restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> *restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                   continueUserActivity:userActivity
                     restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

and also inside app.tsx I have

```
setupLinking = async () => {
    // Listen to links opened when the app is closed
    const initialLink = await Linking.getInitialURL();

    if (initialLink) {
      this.onURLEvent({ url: initialLink });
    }

    // Listen to links opened in the app or when the app is in background
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.onURLEvent);
  };

onURLEvent = async (event: { url: any; }) => {
    const { url } = event;

    if (!url) {
      return;
    }

    const link = getLinkFromDynamicLink(url);
    const eventMethod = getMethodFromLink(link);
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?